# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar varios divs, pero solo uno a la vez?

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un problema, lo que quiero que haga es que cuando haga un click en una imagen de una flecha se levante una sección en una card. El código funciona pero no levanta una sola si no que levanta todas a la vez.

JS

```
 const weather = document.querySelectorAll(".open-weathers");
 const clickOpenMoreInf = function (e){

  const wrapWeathers = document.querySelectorAll(".weathers");
  wrapWeathers.forEach( contInf =>{
    contInf.style.transform="translateY(-175px)";
  })
 }

 weather.forEach(boton =>{
   boton.addEventListener("click", clickOpenMoreInf);
 })
```

HTML

```
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-wrap-info">
     <p class="parrafo-country-city">Cancún, MX</p>
     <img class="img2"src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d.png">
     <p class="actual-temp2"></p>
     <p class="card-parrafo-max2">Temperatura maxíma 31.01°C</p>
     <p class="card-parrafo-min2">Temperatura minima 26.41°C</p>
  <div class="weathers">
     <img class="open-weathers" src="./icons/sort-down-solid.svg">
     <p class="temp-day2">31.01</p>
     <p class="temp-morn2">26.41</p>
     <p class="temp-night2">27.27</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta en rojo es lo que se tiene que levantar, pero al hacer click en la flecha se levantan todas

Comment: estas seleccionando todos los ".weathers" del documento en esta linea const wrapWeathers = document.querySelectorAll(".weathers");. deberias selecionar solo el relacionado con el boton que diste click.

Comment: si tienes dudas en cuanto a lo anterior puedes publicar tu html.

Comment: Estaría genial que nos mostraras la estructura de tu HTML para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @NikolaTesla

ya eh subidoel codigo HTML de una card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comportamiento al hacer clic en un elemento debería ser:

- Restablecer todos, eliminando la propiedad
- Obtener elemento actual con `e.target`
- Desde ahí, obtener el padre con `.closest('div')`
- Aplicar el estilo deseado

```
 const weather = document.querySelectorAll(".open-weathers");
 const clickOpenMoreInf = function (e){
   // Obtener todos los elementos
   const wrapWeathers = document.querySelectorAll(".weathers");
   // Recorrer todos para restablecer estilo
   wrapWeathers.forEach( contInf => {
     // Evitar hacerlo en el elemento que disparó el evento
     if(e.target.closest('div') != contInf) {
         contInf.style.transform = '';
     }
   })
   // Aplicar estilo solo al que corresponde
   let contInf = e.target.closest('div');
   if(contInf.style.transform == '') {
       // No tiene el estilo, aplicarlo
       contInf.style.transform = "translateY(-175px)";
   } else {
       // Ya tiene el estilo, removerlo
       contInf.style.transform = '';
   }
 }

 weather.forEach(boton =>{
   boton.addEventListener("click", clickOpenMoreInf);
 })
```

Sería recomendable agregar o eliminar clase para aplicar los efectos en lugar de hacerlo directamente en el estilo, pero con esto ya debe funcionar.

### Actualización:

Si el elemento ya tiene el efecto, al hacer clic otra vez, lo quita. Pero debo insistir en uso de clases CSS, porque se simplificaría mucho el código, en lugar del `if` bastaría un `elemento.classList.toggle('nombre_de_clase');`, por ejemplo:

```js
     const weather = document.querySelectorAll(".open-weathers");
     const clickOpenMoreInf = function (e){
       // Obtener todos los elementos
       const wrapWeathers = document.querySelectorAll(".weathers");
       // Recorrer todos para restablecer estilo
       wrapWeathers.forEach( contInf => {
         // Evitar hacerlo en el elemento que disparó el evento
         if(e.target.closest('div') != contInf) {
             contInf.classList.remove('active');
         }
       })
       // Aplicar estilo solo al que corresponde
       e.target.closest('div').classList.toggle('active');
     }
    
     weather.forEach(boton =>{
       boton.addEventListener("click", clickOpenMoreInf);
     })
```

```css
.active {
    transform:translateY(-175px);
}
```

```html
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-wrap-info">
     <p class="parrafo-country-city">Cancún, MX</p>
     <img class="img2"src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d.png">
     <p class="actual-temp2"></p>
     <p class="card-parrafo-max2">Temperatura maxíma 31.01°C</p>
     <p class="card-parrafo-min2">Temperatura minima 26.41°C</p>
  <div class="weathers">
     <img class="open-weathers" src="./icons/sort-down-solid.svg">
     <p class="temp-day2">31.01</p>
     <p class="temp-morn2">26.41</p>
     <p class="temp-night2">27.27</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="card">
   <div class="card-wrap-info">
     <p class="parrafo-country-city">Cancún, MX</p>
     <img class="img2"src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d.png">
     <p class="actual-temp2"></p>
     <p class="card-parrafo-max2">Temperatura maxíma 31.01°C</p>
     <p class="card-parrafo-min2">Temperatura minima 26.41°C</p>
  <div class="weathers">
     <img class="open-weathers" src="./icons/sort-down-solid.svg">
     <p class="temp-day2">31.01</p>
     <p class="temp-morn2">26.41</p>
     <p class="temp-night2">27.27</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Gracias!! bro me funciono

Comment: @FernandoDelgado, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: ok ya esta listo

Comment: oie bro, tengo un problemilla quise intentarlo solo pero no pude xd,  cuando se haces click y se alza esa seccion (eso fuciona bien) pero si haces click nuevamente  para que se baje este ya no se baja... Hasta que hagas click en otro elemento

Comment: @FernandoDelgado, listo, revisa la actualización

Comment: nuevamente te lo vuelvo a agradecer broo. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

No estas usando el evento ligado a tus `EventListener`, si no que estas apuntando a todos tus elementos que tengan la clase `weathers` como podemos observar aqui en la funcion `clickOpenMoreInf`:

```
wrapWeathers.forEach( contInf =>{
    contInf.style.transform="translateY(-175px)";
})
```

La forma mas facil de arreglar esto es simplemente usando el evento ligado al `EventListener`, mediante su propiedad `target` de esta manera:

```
const weather = document.querySelectorAll(".open-weathers");
const clickOpenMoreInf = function (e){
    e.target.style.transform="translateY(-175px)";
}

weather.forEach(boton =>{
   boton.addEventListener("click", clickOpenMoreInf);
})
```

De esta manera la accion solo ocurriria con el boton clikeado de la tarjeta y no todos.

Sin embargo como no haz puesto `html` no me queda claro cual de las dos clases (`.open-weathers` o `weathers`) es los botones, supongo será `.open-weathers`.

Si es asi el codigo cumplira con su proposito.

En caso contrario los eventos oyentes deben ser añadidos a los elementos que conformen los botones como tal y no la tarjeta.

**Nota**: la propiedad target de un evento oyente hace referencia al elemento actual en el que se desencadeno la accion del evento oyente, por lo cual es perfecto para tu proposito. tambien existe `currentTarget`, pero en ocasiones `currentTarget` es diferente a `target`, esto dependera si hay subcontenedores o no.

Comment: Por cierto, estas usando `forEach` en el resultado de un `querySelectorAll` y se me hace raro que esto no haya dado problemas. si te da un error debido al `forEach` me dices y edito la pregunta para poder que puedas usar el `forEach`. ya que normalmente el resultado de un `querySelectorAll` no es directamente iterable con un `forEach`.

Comment: por qué dices que el resultado de un **querySellectorAll** no es directamente iterable con un **forEach** has intentado mostrar por consola lo que te trae **querySellectorAll** ?? Nos trae un **nodeList** de solo lectura, por lo que al ser una lista de nodos puedes iterarlo con un **forEach** sin problema, has intentado mostrar por consola que es un **querySellectorAll**?? Te invito a que lo hagas con **typeOf** has intentado poner un **.length** al resultado de querySellectorAll ? Te invito a leer más sobre el peculiar caso de **querySellectorAll** fliparas de lo interesante que es.

Comment: Que te arroja cuando imprimes por consola el resultado de un **querySellectorAll** ?que te arroja cuan imprimes **typeOf** al resultado de un **querySellectorAll**? que te arroja cuando imprimes **.length** al resultado de un **querySellectorAll** ?Me extraña que si lo has intentado muchas veces no logres comprender el por qué **forEach** itera sin problema el resultado de un querySellectorAll.

Comment: Si, aparentemente me he confundido, lo que no se puede iterar con un `forEach` es un `HTMLCollection`, el cual me ha salido en otras ocasiones en ionic, tienes razon, aquello que hizo el usuario es valido.

Comment: Me he confundido porque normalmente no uso `querySelectorAll`, uso es simplemente `querySelector`, el cual si retorna un `HTMLCollection`. se agradece la critica constructiva, error mio.

Comment: igual te invito a que hagas el experimento de imprimir por consola lo que te dije antes, fliparas del interesante comportamiento de **querySellectorAll** me extraño tu respuesta, por eso decidí comentarte, ya que podrías confundir al usuario. Recuerdas que me habías dicho que eras un veterano en este blog?? Bueno ando siguiendo tus pasos para aprender de los veteranos, Saludos desde México.

Comment: @NikolaTesla saludos desde colombia, no me considero veterano (hable en tercera persona cuando me referia a veteranos), si, realice la ejecucion del codigo y me di cuenta de mi error en ese preciso instante, debe ser por lo poco que uso el `querySelector`, me acostumbre demasiado a usar los especificos para cada tipo (id, tag, clase) etc, igual el `querySelector` y `querySelectorAll` tienen mucho potencial y deberia comenzar a usarlos, aunque me extrana que `querySelector` devuelva algo diferente a `querySelectorAll`, en fin creo que consideraria mas util el `nodeList` al `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: @Riven con el target no funciono del todo bien, lo que quiero es que hacer click el la imagen con la clase open-weather, es que el div con la clase weathers se valla hacia ariba (este div es el contiene la img y 3 parrafos)

ya eh editado la publicacion y ya eh subido el html de una card